# Windows Server 2003 (IIS 6) - Locating my FTP

Tags: windows, ftp

We have a Windows 2003 Server running IIS6, which was setup long before my time.

Now that I've had a request to set-up an isolated FTP user account for a client (so that they have access to their own website only), I can't actually find what FTP program is being used, and thus I'm unable to set-up their account.

It doesn't appear to be using the FTP system integrated into IIS6, as the FTProot folder that the only and default FTP Site is pointing to is empty. And I've also went through the programs list to no avail.

Is there any way to trace back to find what FTP Application our FTP is set-up on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use Sysinternals (found at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals) to see
which process is
- writing/reading to the FTPRoot area of the disk
- sending/receiving traffic to the FTP port on the machine

Comment: Thanks Phil. Do you happen to know which Sysinternals utility would do this?